# SQLite bug or wrong query

Tags: sqlite

I create a dabatabase with around 3M rows in SQLite, I use it also to test functions or small experiments. My  last experiment is to check  the distribution of a random function so I wrote this query:

```
SELECT b.a , count(*)
FROM(
    SELECT abs(random()) % 10 a
    FROM fdic) b 
GROUP BY b.a 
ORDER BY b.a
```

It works with each SQLite database, just replace the table fdic with your table.
And I get the follow response:

| a | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 318161 |
| 9 | 316810 |
| 5 | 317591 |
| 9 | 316006 |
| 2 | 317502 |
| 6 | 317131 |
| 6 | 316093 |
| 6 | 318442 |
| 2 | 317923 |
| 6 | 316793 |

Of course you are not going to have twice the same answer due the random() function. But if you analyze the answer there is two problems, the first is that does not "group", there is for example 4 times the value 6, twice the value 2 and so on.
The second problem is that does not sort, the values are not sorted.
So before to report a bug, I would ask to you:

**do you notice an error in my query?**

(the db with the table fdic is on-line, I do not know if Stackoverflow allows to post the address, if you need the db just ask in the commentairs)

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT b.a , count(*) FROM(SELECT abs(random()) % 10 a FROM fdic) b GROUP BY b.a ORDER BY b.a;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     46    0                    0   Start at 46
1     Noop           2     4     0                    0   
2     SorterOpen     3     1     0     k(1,B)         0   
3     Integer        0     2     0                    0   r[2]=0; clear abort flag
4     Null           0     5     5                    0   r[5..5]=NULL
5     Gosub          4     42    0                    0   
6     OpenRead       1     2     0     0              0   root=2 iDb=0; fdic
7     Rewind         1     15    0                    0   
8       Function       0     0     10    random(0)      0   r[10]=func()
9       Function       0     10    9     abs(1)         0   r[9]=func(r[10])
10      Remainder      11    9     8                    0   r[8]=r[9]%r[11]
11      ClrSubtype     8     0     0                    0   r[8].subtype = 0
12      MakeRecord     8     1     9                    0   r[9]=mkrec(r[8])
13      SorterInsert   3     9     0                    0   key=r[9]
14    Next           1     8     0                    1   
15    OpenPseudo     4     8     1                    0   1 columns in r[8]
16    SorterSort     3     45    0                    0   GROUP BY sort
17      SorterData     3     8     4                    0   r[8]=data
18      Column         4     0     6                    0   r[6]= cursor 4 column 0
19      Compare        5     6     1     k(1,B)         0   r[5] <-> r[6]
20      Jump           21    25    21                   0   
21      Move           6     5     1                    0   r[5]=r[6]
22      Gosub          3     32    0                    0   output one row
23      IfPos          2     45    0                    0   if r[2]>0 then r[2]-=0, goto 45; check abort flag
24      Gosub          4     42    0                    0   reset accumulator
25      AggStep        0     0     7     count(0)       0   accum=r[7] step(r[0])
26      Integer        1     1     0                    0   r[1]=1; indicate data in accumulator
27    SorterNext     3     17    0                    0   
28    Gosub          3     32    0                    0   output final row
29    Goto           0     45    0                    0   
30    Integer        1     2     0                    0   r[2]=1; set abort flag
31    Return         3     0     0                    0   
32    IfPos          1     34    0                    0   if r[1]>0 then r[1]-=0, goto 34; Groupby result generator entry point
33    Return         3     0     0                    0   
34    AggFinal       7     0     0     count(0)       0   accum=r[7] N=0
35    Function       0     0     10    random(0)      0   r[10]=func()
36    Function       0     10    9     abs(1)         0   r[9]=func(r[10])
37    Remainder      11    9     12                   0   r[12]=r[9]%r[11]
38    ClrSubtype     12    0     0                    0   r[12].subtype = 0
39    Copy           7     13    0                    0   r[13]=r[7]
40    ResultRow      12    2     0                    0   output=r[12..13]
41    Return         3     0     0                    0   end groupby result generator
42    Null           0     7     7                    0   r[7..7]=NULL
43    Integer        0     1     0                    0   r[1]=0; indicate accumulator empty
44    Return         4     0     0                    0   
45    Halt           0     0     0                    0   
46    Transaction    0     0     2     1              1   usesStmtJournal=0
47    Integer        10    11    0                    0   r[11]=10
48    Goto           0     1     0                    0
```

See lines 8 and 35: the subquery is executed twice. This can happen in many database engines, not just SQLite. Normally, this shouldn't matter, as repeating a query doesn't change the result.

Comment: A quick question, how do I detect in the explain that SQLite uses the index? Something such SeekGE, IdxGT, DeferredSeek?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77666238/8398549), the engine is re-executing the `random()` when grouping the results, instead of working with results directly.

You need to *materialize* the results if you want to avoid such nasty surprise (`WITH a AS ... SELECT ...` won't work neither) :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE AS
SELECT abs(random()) % 10 a
FROM fdic;

SELECT a, count(*)
FROM TEMP_TABLE
GROUP BY a
ORDER BY a;
```

Results :

| a | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 |
| 1 | 14 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 5 | 13 |
| 6 | 21 |
| 7 | 19 |
| 8 | 19 |
| 9 | 21 |

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kpxxnHskUQzaKQUH9VTG7J/0)